# Cordova In-App browser opening external scripts

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

//Actual webscript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var lhnAccountN = "310904-1";
   var lhnButtonN = 38;
   var lhnInviteEnabled = 1;
   var lhnWindowN = 0;
   var lhnDepartmentN = 36316;
   var lhnChatPosition = 'bottomright';
</script>

<a href="http://www.livehelpnow.net/products/live-chat-system" target="_blank" style="font-size:10px;" id="lhnHelp">best live chat</a>

<script src="//www.livehelpnow.net/lhn/widgets/chatbutton/lhnchatbutton-current.min.js" type="text/javascript" id="lhnscript"></script>
```

//the data is storing on session. every time connection is lost.

//so I'm using in-app browser to open the script in ionic mobile app. I'm unable to open the window please help me out

```
$rootScope.testChat=function(){
    var options = {
         location: 'no',
         clearcache: 'yes',
         toolbar: 'yes'
     };

      var ref=window.open('http://www.livehelpnow.net/products/live-chat-system', '_blank', options);

        ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
        ref.executeScript({
        code:"var lhnAccountN = '310904-1';var lhnButtonN = 38;var lhnInviteEnabled = 1;var lhnWindowN = 0;var lhnDepartmentN = 36316;var lhnChatPosition = 'bottomright';"
    })
    ref.executeScript({
        code:"var chat; chat.src='www.livehelpnow.net/lhn/widgets/chatbutton/lhnchatbutton-current.min.js' chat.id='lhnscript'"
    })
})
} 
 <a href="http://www.livehelpnow.net/products/live-chat-system" target="_blank" style="font-size:10px;"ng-click="testChat()" id="lhnHelp">best live chat</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace window.open() function with cordova.InAppBrowser.open(). You can consult https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html for further info .

Comment: Hi we are unable to load the script. the in-app browser is working great.The window is opened.

Comment: @HarishKesari try writing the whole script in a js file and then try to load the script. Use inspect device to find any error which may occur during the execution.